# MySQL Connector/C++ error in while loop

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

```
void dataProcess::loginProcess(byte* packet, uint16_t length)
{
    unique_ptr<ResultSet> res;
    unique_ptr<Statement> stmt;
    byte idPacket[4] = {packet[9], packet[8], packet[7], packet[6]};
    uint32_t id, account_id;
    string account_pass, account_type;
    id = decodeToInt(idPacket, 4);
    account_pass = decodeToChar(packet, 14, length - 1);
    account_type = decodeToChar(packet, 10, 11);
    stmt.reset(this->con->createStatement());
    res.reset(stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM account_info"));
    while(res->next())
    {
        account_id = res->getUInt("id");
        if(lowerCase(account_type).compare("ts") == 0)
        {
            if((account_id == id) && (account_pass.compare(res->getString("password")) == 0))
            {
                sendPacket("F4440300010300");
            }
            else
            {
                wrongPass();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wrongPass();
        }
    }
}
```

so the above function is being called once in each iteration of an infinite while loop and the function always failed at the 2nd iteration. I think this is somehow related to the deletion of the ResultSet object at the first iteration because when I try using a normal pointer and using the delete statement the same problem occurs but if I remove the delete it can get through the 2nd iteration but I'm quite sure that the ResultSet needs to be deleted according to the example on MySQL website. I am quite new to mysql Connector/C++ so I am very unsure to what is causing this problem. From debugging it appears to fail at this line on the second iteration.

```
res.reset(stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM account_info"));
```

This is the error that appears after the program enters the second iteration

```
Error in `./server': free(): invalid size: 0x00007f8214004ca0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x790cb)[0x7f8219aa70cb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8275a)[0x7f8219ab075a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f8219ab418c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so.7(_ZN5boost20checked_array_deleteIc                          EEvPT_+0x1f)[0x7f821a9397df]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so.7(_ZN5boost12scoped_arrayIcED1Ev+0x                          1b)[0x7f821a9390b5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so.7(_ZN3sql5mysql15MySQL_ResultSetC2E                          N5boost10shared_ptrINS0_9NativeAPI22NativeResultsetWrapperEEENS2_8weak_ptrINS4_2                          3NativeConnectionWrapperEEENS_9ResultSet9enum_typeEPNS0_15MySQL_StatementERNS3_I                          NS0_17MySQL_DebugLoggerEEE+0x205)[0x7f821a98cde3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlcppconn.so.7(_ZN3sql5mysql15MySQL_Statement12e                          xecuteQueryERKNS_9SQLStringE+0x11b)[0x7f821a99443f]
./server(+0x326e)[0x56192448126e]
./server(+0x2f40)[0x561924480f40]
./server(+0x2da3)[0x561924480da3]
./server(+0x2a45)[0x561924480a45]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ca)[0x7f8219dfc6ca]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5f)[0x7f8219b360af]
```

class and the constructor:

```
class dataProcess : public thread
{
    public:
        dataProcess(int sock);
        virtual ~dataProcess();

    protected:
    virtual void thread_handler();
    private:
    void wrongPass();
    void loginProcess(byte* packet, uint16_t length);
    void sendPacket(string packet);
    int sock;
    player* p;
    Driver* driver;
    unique_ptr<Connection> con;
};
dataProcess::dataProcess(int sock)
{
    this->sock = sock;
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con.reset(driver->connect("localhost", "root", "password"));
    con->setSchema("ts_server");
    thread::startThread();
}
```

Comment: is the `res` declared in the function as posted? or is it actually in the class of which this function is a member? I only ask because you would only get an invalid free if `res` was pointing to something deleted (not possible in your post). otherwise it would have to be in `executeQuery()`

Comment: please show the code where you loop around this function

Comment: so the loop is simply just a while(1) with the function inside it. 'res' is declared in the function which is why I'm very confused to how it could failed on the second iteration. Also note that the 'Driver' and 'Connection con' are declared in the class.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x this is the constructor `dataProcess::dataProcess(int sock)  
{  
    this->sock = sock;  
    driver = get_driver_instance();  
    con.reset(driver->connect("localhost", "root", "password"));  
    con->setSchema("ts_server");  thread::startThread();  
}`

Comment: then the problem is within `executeQuery()` as the stacktrace suggests, which means either the library screwed up or you're using it wrong. unfortunately I don't know enough about mysqlconnector to help

Comment: @vu1p3n0x it appears problem maybe related to `Connection con` because when I attempt a simpler code with a while(1) with the same format after the second iteration I get the error that "connection has been closed" eventhough the connection was not closed

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I have solved this problem and I have learned a very important lesson as a newbie. The problem occurs due to the undefined behaviour caused by my carelessness to ensure I have "deleted all my dynamically allocated variables" Once I have added delete in the right place everything works perfectly. so anyone facing these kind of random problems make sure to check these :)